# Analyzing Likert Data for Correlations Between Grouped Items

Tags: spss, likert

I'm analyzing data from a 1-5 Likert Scale, and I'm not sure which test to use (I'll be using SPSS). My issue is that I'm not trying to determine the correlation between *all* items, but the correlation between *groups* of items. So, items 1 through 4 measure one construct, items 5-8 measure another construct, and so on for 4 separate constructs of 4 items each (16 items in the Likert Scale Survey) which are all related to the same topic. Basically, I'm trying to determine how a given score on each item group correlates to the other item groups. I think my pitfall is that I lack the proper nomenclature to effectively search for the solution.

I'm sorry in advance if this question has been answered elsewhere, but I'm having a difficult time searching for it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered factor analysis? Are you interested in exploring these relationships or confirming that your expected structure is reasonable?

Comment: I have considered it, yes. I was told by my professor (this is for a class) that I should avoid factor analysis due to the fact the we're required to keep our sample size small. For my purposes, N=26, and he told me that I should simply find the correlations between these item groups, but offered little else in terms of advice, unfortunately. The overall Cronbach's alpha of the entire dataset is .38, and is pretty meaningless for my purposes. I'm interested in exploring these relationships, but not sure if I can perform an Exploratory Factor Analysis. Hence, my dilemma.